# Representation of a set

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to represent all the sets in roster form? 
I have a question given in my elementary algebra book.
State $True$ or $False$ : "Any set can be represented in/by the roster/listing form/method"
I think this statement is $True$ because every set can be represented in the roster form. 
But is there a way to prove this so that the statement can be generalized. Is there a way to prove this using any mathematical method.

I'm currently in my freshman year maybe this is because I can't think of any method to prove this statement. Kindly make things clear to me.

Comment: What is the roster/listing form method? Do you mean $X=\{y :C(y)\}$ where $C$ is some condition?

Comment: A set in Roster form is represented by a list of symbols. Since any list is at most countable, it follows that this set must be countable. So, for example, there is no Roster form for the set of real numbers, which is not countable.

Comment: @Crostul this implies that it's not possible to represent every set in roster form. You are saying that we cannot represent infinite set in roster form.

Comment: I am saying that there are some infinite sets having no roster form: these are exactly all uncountable sets. So the answer to your question is "False".

Comment: @user254665 no roster form is also known as listing method or tabular form. All of them are same. While you are talking about set builder method. In roster form elements are separated by commas.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, but anyway: what is the roster form of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Crostul yeah I understood your point because set of real numbers, irrational numbers or rational numbers cannot be represented in roster form.

Comment: No: you didnt' understand, because for example rational numbers have a roster form.

Comment: @Crostul but there are infinite rational numbers how can we represent the set of all rational numbers in roster form.

Comment: If $\{ x_n \}_{n \ge 1}$ is an enumeration of $\Bbb{Q}$, then you have $\{ x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , \dots \}$. These are separated by commas, aren't they?

Comment: @Crostul But how will you decide $n$ in this case.

Comment: @Crostul They are of course separated by commas but te set will not include all rational numbers.